# When my PS4 turns off my controller turns off and when I reboot it, it can’t turn on

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

I was playing on my play station one day and it seemed fine. But then I came back the next day and my controller wouldn’t turn on or charge. I went and got a new one only for it to almost immediately stop charging and I couldn’t turn it back on. The next day I got the Sony charger port that you stick the controllers in and again it didn’t work. I’ve used three other older controllers to no success. What should I do?

Comment: I have experienced that same issue, though only with one controller. I followed [these instructions](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-ps4-controller-wont-charge/) bar replacing the battery - otherwise everything else was not applicable.